# Can we get Google map layers through OpenLayers proxy configuration

Tags: google-maps, proxy

I have a client which is in the LAN and doesn't have internet connection. It can get all the required layers from the web server through LAN only. but the web server has the internet connection.
Now the question is, how to render Google map layers from this client which doesn't have internet connection?

Hope I will get reply soon to solve my problem.

Comment: > just a quick of 2 my cents: Using mapproxy.org without caching for google maps > and deploy it as a reverse proxy on the webserver. Can you explain your idea [VietThanh Le](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/296/vietthanh-le) please?

Answer (score 2):

Using the Google Maps tiles outside of the Google Maps API is, in every case I'm aware of, a violation of the Google Maps Terms of Service. The Google Maps API does not have an ability to change where it is loading map tiles from.

I think your only solution here is to use the web server (which does, apparently, have internet access?) as a general web proxy at the browser level. Anything which tries to load the Google Maps tiles in any other way would probably be considered a violation of the terms of service.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick of 2 my cents: Using mapproxy.org without caching for google maps and deploy it as a reverse proxy on the webserver.